# How to use webpack-chain to add appendTsSuffixTo options to ts-loader?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, webpack, webpack-chain

Simply put, how do I use webpack-loader to add the following option to the `ts-loader` plugin:

```
options: {
  appendTsSuffixTo: [/\.vue$/]
}
```

Currently I have this setup for ts-loader (the top part is here for context). the bottom `config.plugin` call is the area giving me trouble.

```
    chainWebpack: config => {
      config.module
        .rule('typescript')
        .test(/\.tsx?$/)
        .exclude
          .add(/node_modules/)
          .end()
        .use('ts-loader')
          .loader('ts-loader'),

      config
        .plugin('ts-loader')
        .tap( args => { return { appendTsSuffixTo: [/\.vue$/] } }
        )
    }
```

But this throws an exception:

> Cannot read property '__expression' of undefined

The [webpack-loader docs](https://github.com/neutrinojs/webpack-chain/blob/master/README.md#config-plugins-modify-arguments) don't describe exactly what should be done when adding the option.

What do I need to do to add this option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into the section on [modifying options](https://github.com/neutrinojs/webpack-chain/blob/master/README.md#config-module-rules-uses-loaders-modifying-options) for loaders:

```
config.module
  .rule('typescript')
  .use('ts-loader')
    .tap(options => merge(options, {
      appendTsSuffixTo: [/\.vue$/]
    }));
```

**Update**

Here's the relevant docs for [merging](https://github.com/neutrinojs/webpack-chain/blob/master/README.md#merging-config) objects.

This [GitHub](https://github.com/neutrinojs/webpack-chain/issues/138#issuecomment-454159573) thread provides good examples.

```
// preserve existing options
config.module
  .rule('typescript')
  .use('ts-loader')
    .tap(options => ({ ...options, {
      appendTsSuffixTo: [/\.vue$/]
    }}));
```

Comment: Hi, is the `merge` call in error in that example? That's not something that I have defined. I imagine it's merging the objects, but I don't want to make any assumptions with webpack...

Comment: Nope, [merge](https://github.com/neutrinojs/webpack-chain/blob/master/README.md#chainedmap) is a method available through chainmap. The `merge` in the answer is actually verbatim from the documents.

Comment: Gotcha. Not sure why the docs use `merge` by itself, I get an error that merge is not defined. I need to use `config.merge()`. Though that throws the error `omit.includes is not a function`...

Comment: Note, the `omit.includes is not a function` is my fault.  I have a `,` at the end of my chain. If you update your answer with the additional `options()` info from [here](https://github.com/neutrinojs/webpack-chain/issues/138) I will accept your answer.

Comment: I'm not sure why they use merge that way either, maybe it's just assumed to be destructured from the config object. That GitHub thread is a good resource with clear examples, thanks for linking it!